# Are there "chain complexes" and "homology groups" taking values in pairs of topological spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, chain-complexes, reference-request, gn.general-topology

Throughout this question, notation of the form $(X,A)$ denotes a sufficiently nice pair of topological spaces. I think for most of what I'm saying here, it is enough to assume that the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ is a [cofibration](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hurewicz+cofibration), or that $(X,A)$ is a neighborhood deformation retract ([NDR](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/neighborhood+retract)) pair. All maps $f:(X,A) \to (Y,B)$ are continuous and satisfy $f(A) \subset B$.

Consider a sequence $\mathcal{S}$ given by: $$\ldots \to (X_{n-1},A_{n-1}) \stackrel{d_{n-1}}{\to} (X_n,A_n) \stackrel{d_n}{\to} (X_{n+1},A_{n+1}) \to \ldots$$ so that $d_n \circ d_{n-1}(X_{n-1}) \subset A_{n+1}$ for each $n$.

> Has this object been defined and studied? If so, where?

One can associate to this sequence of space-pairs a "homology" which takes values in the category of space-pairs. That is, define $$\mathcal{HT}_n(\mathcal{S}) = \left(d_n^{-1}(A_{n+1}),d_{n-1}(X_{n-1})\right).$$ The construction is functorial if one considers the obvious analogue of "chain maps" in the category which contains objects like $\mathcal{S}$. I'm wondering if basic definitions and properties, etc. of this or related constructions have been set down somewhere.

Comment: Where did you meet this structure? In a concrete problem or just out of curiosity?

Comment: Johannes: somewhere in between. I'd call it concretely-motivated curiosity. My thesis work involved simplifying a filtered cell complex via discrete Morse theory in a way that preserved algebraic topological invariants (persistent homology groups). As such, I find the process of constructing massive chain groups and then taking a huge quotient somewhat inefficient, and was wondering if there is a "compact representation" (both words used non-technically) of some object in the category of topological spaces itself from which one could derive the invariants whenever necessary.

Comment: @Vidit: You mention a "filtered cell complex".  The book "Nonabelian algebraic topology" (2011) see my web page, http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html , builds algebraic topology **directly** from filtered spaces, via homotopically defined functors. Problem 16.1.17 is about relating these methods to Morse Theory. 

Comment: Thank you, Ronnie. I already have your book(s), being a fan if the groupoid point of view, so I will take a look.

Comment: @Vidit: Reading your question again, I would be inclined to go for defining invariants of bifiltered spaces, rather than invariants in spaces.  Such bifiltered spaces in truncated form can be regarded as special cases of $n$-cubes of spaces, to which my work with Loday applies. I'm slowly writing up something on the bifiltered case, and my exposition  [60]  ``Triadic Van Kampen theorems and Hurewicz theorems'', Algebraic  Topology, Proc. Int. Conf. March 1988, Edited
M.Mahowald and S.Priddy,  _Cont. Math._ 96 (1989) 39-57. (pdf on my web site) gives an idea. Also I missed the word "discrete"!

Comment: Ronnie, I'm not sure I see an "obvious" bifiltration anywhere in this question. Could you explain why that would be the natural thing to do? I am happy to discuss this via email if things get too intricate for comment boxes.

Comment: @Vidit: I've sent an email on this. One point is that a pair $(X,S)$ defines filtrations $E_n(X,A)$ which are a base point in dim $0$, $A$ in levels $1$ to $n-1$ and $X$ thereafter. So if $X$ already has a filtration $X_*$ then we get two filtrations for a given $n$.  

Comment: The pair should be $(X,A)$ of course. 

Comment: @ViditNanda This is two years old by now. Did you make any progress?